# Grafana & Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, graphite, influxdb, grafana

I have an analytics node in my cluster, with cassandra setup on it. The metrics from all the nodes in my clusters (like CPU, memory etc) are pulled into my cassandra database on regular intervals. The contents of the cassandra db are accessible via REST API. I can simply query via a url and it will return all the required data in JSON format.

Now is it possible to integrate grafana directly with cassandra using the REST api or do I need to put the data into other data source (like influxdb or graphite) for grafana to be able to display??